# Breaking Tkinter Loop Without Using after()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop, tkinter-button

Question written in Python 3.9.7

This is a hypothetical question. I was entertaining this thought for a project of mine before I realized a much easier alternative, but I'm still curious how you might do this, especially since it might improve my understanding of tkinter and while loops.

Say you have something that needs to be run continuously. You can achieve this easily with a while loop, but what if you wanted to break the loop with a button in tkinter?

I'm familiar with the typical solution. Something like this gets the job done by employing the after() method on the root widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

runningLoop = False

def loop():
    if running:
        #do something
    
    root.after(1, loop)

def start:
    global running
    running = True

def stop:
    global running
    running = False

startButton = tk.Button(root, text = "filler text", command = start).pack(side = tk.TOP)
stopButton = tk.Button(root, text = "filler text", command = stop).pack(side = tk.TOP)

root.after(1, loop)

root.mainloop()
```

However, there's always some form of delay as a requisite of the after function that is, at minimum, 1 ms. What if you wanted there to be no delay? What if you wanted to run the loop as quickly as possible until the stop button is pressed, like a while loop without a break condition does until the program is interrupted? That is how while loops work, right? Is there not a way to more smoothly run the loop continuously without the delay and still have a stop button functionality? Would something like that have to invoke threading or parallel programming techniques?

I ask this only because the delay of the after function is not a problem (and some cases, it's a feature) for most answers on how to do something like this out there that I've seen. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use multiple threads. The button can kill the other thread.

Comment: A while loop happening means, the thread is blocked and no events will be processed by the `mainloop`. Which is why we run `while` in a different thread, though it is not conventional. But incase you are curious, you can continue while loop with a flag and then once the button is clicked, set the flag to `False` and check if the value of flag is ever `False` and if it is, then break.

Comment: @Barmar Are threads kill-able?

Comment: They are, but it's better to use the condition variable.